# Flutter Firestore - Instance of 'Future <dynamic>' Error

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a code like this:

```
  name = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc("${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}").get().then((value) => value.data()!["name"]).toString();
```

I get the following output from this code:

```
 Instance of 'Future <dynamic>'
```

How can I resolve this error?

[image]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `await` to `Future` to get the returned value.

```
var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc("${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}").get();

if(snapshot.data!=null){
name=snapshot.data!['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'name' is already in a string, you don't need to use toString() Try removing that.